# How do I pass variables to a view builder's renderer?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm creating a module that will render a few nodes before getting back the result and print it as PDF. (I can't use wkhtmltopdf; I wish I could.)

So far, I managed to make my controller/action use the template I wanted, and anything I write in the template file is showed with `die($html)`. However, I can't find any example of how to pass variables to the view; I tried a few things, but I got nothing, excepted 500 errors.

This is the code I am using.

```
public function nodeAction(NodeInterface $node) {
  // Here, I define a variable named $responses that contains a lot of datas as arrays
  $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
  $build = $view_builder->view($node, 'cnas_pdf');
  $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build, ['var' => $response]);

  // No error in this configuration, but "var" is nowhere to be found
  die($html);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible to add parameters to renderPlain(). What you can do depends. If you want to use a variable inside of the node, then do this in a node preprocess hook. But more likely you want to add additional elements to the build array before you render it, for example:

```
$build = [];
$build['top'] = ['#markup' => 'abc'];
$build['node'] = $view_builder->view($node, 'cnas_pdf');
$build['footer'] = ['#markup' => 'xyz'];
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll have to use the preprocess_hook(), thank you

Answer (score 4):

This might be a slightly different scenario than your original question, but I stumbled across while searching for ways to add custom variables to an entity's template at the time that I build it with the ViewBuilder, versus altering existing variables in a preprocess. Hopefully this should be helpful.

The ViewBuilder's `view()` method returns a render array, so you can use that to pass your custom variables to the template.

```
public function nodeAction(NodeInterface $node) {
  // Here, I define a variable named $responses that contains a lot of datas as arrays
  $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
  $build = $view_builder->view($node, 'cnas_pdf');
  $build['#my_response'] = $response;
  $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);

  // No error in this configuration, but "var" is nowhere to be found
  die($html);
}
```

After modifying the `$build` to include the new array key, you should have access to it in your node's template, such as with `{{ elements['#my_response'] }}` in this case. If you wanted to make this a bit cleaner in a preprocess, you could then do something like:

```
/**
 * Implements theme_preprocess_node().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#my_response'])) {
    $variables['my_response'] = $variables['elements']['#my_response'];
  }
}
```

You would then be able to access it in your template directly with `{{ my_response }}`.

Comment: Pretty clever solution. Nice!

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks a lot.